# PHP: How can I get the URL that has been rewritten with mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

For example, if I rewrite `/category/topic/post/` to `/index.php?cat=1&topic=2&post=3`, how can I get `/index.php?cat=1&topic=2&post=3` using PHP?

Comment: Short answer: You cannot. However, if your application knows the rewrite scheme (ie. you have reverse mapping) or you have well-defined rewrite rules, you can reverse the rewrite process.

Comment: @Emre `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will do the job just fine on Apache server and IIS 7.x if URL Rewrite module v2 is used.

Comment: why do you want this url? there may be an easier solution to accomplishing what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @LazyOne You are right, I had forgotten that.

Comment: for mod_rewrite extraction & debug bookmark this link: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html

Answer (score 14):

You can recreate it pretty easily. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will still give you the correct file name for the script. This should do the trick:

```
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$parts = array();
foreach( $_GET as $k=>$v ) {
    $parts[] = "$k=" . urlencode($v);
}

$url .= "?" . implode("&", $parts);
```

`$url` will now be the URL you're looking for.

EDIT: @carpereret's answer is far better. Upvote him instead

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STING'];` contains the query string exactly as it was sent. No need to recompose it. This could be more simply expressed as.
`$url = implode('?', array_filter([$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']]));`

Comment: -1, because carpereret's answer gives something else and yours is the correct answer. I don't know why you edited your post and made it invalid. You should remove it.

Answer (score 9):

original uri should be in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Good one. Also, this will give your the full url shown on the browser's address bar in case you are rewriting it.

Comment: This does the opposite of what the OP asked for. OP is asking how to get the URL as it was rewritten, not its original form.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get the URL received by PHP after being rewritten with mod_rewrite in Apache:

```
 $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

You can compare this url with the actual url in the browser to debug any rewrite rules in .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You can set environment variable in mod_rewrite rule and then use it in PHP.
Example:

mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(category)/(topic)/(post)/$ /index.php?cat=$1&topic=$2&post=$3 [L,QSA,E=INDEX_URI:/index.php?cat=$1&topic=$2&post=$3]
```

PHP:

```
$index_uri = $_SERVER['INDEX_URI'];
```