# how do I get the visible URL (not that actual URL) in PHP after using htaccess rewrites?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the URL in the address bar using PHP, but `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns that path to the actual file, not the URL I'm created using .htaccess. For example, if my file is at

```
example.com/files/example.php
```

But I've changes the url to:

```
example.com/example
```

I want to get the prettier URL, using PHP, not the actual path. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is returning the actual path.

Comment: @this.lau_ Not a duplicate. That answer will get the url after the redirect

Comment: Surely if you know how you're rewriting the url in the htaccess file you can easily use the same logic in php on $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to make your rewritten url? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588661/php-how-can-i-get-the-url-that-has-been-rewritten-with-mod-rewrite answer may help you.

Comment: I dont get it `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will return what is in the address bar, unless your doing something wacky with your rewrites, show them if you can.

Comment: @Basic, you're correct, I guess the duplicate should the question/answer mentioned by user1.

Answer (score 1):

If your server redirects the browser to the new URL, you could get the old URL from `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$prettyUrl= str_replace(array('files/', '.php'), ' ', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Obviously different logic depending on what page and its corresponding htaccess rewrite.

Though of course as you're referring to $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] one would assume you're talking about a redirect? and if so that url should rewritten already as it's sent from the browser.